# Sending Multiple Paramters in Template Column of MVC 4 Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, telerik

Below code sending only one parameter ( id = o.nopCategoryID ) to controller, how can i send another parameter along with this?

**View**

```
            @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Mappings)        
                .Name("Grid")
                .Scrollable(c => c.Height("200px"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(o => o.ClockCategoryid).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.nopCategoryID).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.nopCategory).Width(100).Title("Category");                               

                    columns.Bound(e => e.ClockCategory).Width(200).Title("Mapped To").Template(t => t.ClockCategory.Replace(",", "<br />"));

                    columns.Bound(o => o.nopCategoryID)
                                        .Width(50)
                                        .Centered()
                                        .Template(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditProduct", new { id = o.nopCategoryID, category = o.nopCategory }))
                                        .Title("Edit");
                    columns.Bound(o => o.nopCategoryID)
                                        .Width(50)
                                        .Centered()
                                        .Template(o => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteMapping", new { id = o.ClockCategoryid }))
                                        .Title("Delete");        
                })

                )
```

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult EditProduct(int id,string category)
    {            
        return Configure(id, 0);
    }
```

Comment: You can just write `new { id = o.nopCategoryID, otherParameterName = otherParemterValue }`...

Comment: already tried, but in controller i get null value for second paramter

Comment: Then please post your your controller action! And also how you tried to call it with the two parameter.

Comment: please find controller code as well as the modified view as specified by you.